# check if the name are duplicate in email column

Tags: r

i have a data frame like below, now i want to check if name before @ are duplicate, if duplicate then mutate new column to(1,0) for TRUE and FALSE

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                 city=c("del","mum","nav","pun","bang","chen","triv","vish","del","mum","bang","vish","bhop","kol","noi","gurg"),
                 email = c("akash.dev@gmail.com","rahul.singh@gmail.com","salman.abbas@gmail.com","ram.lal@gmail.com","ram.lal@gmail.com","prabal.garg@gmail.com","sanu.ali@gmail.com","kunal.singh@gmail.com","lakhan.tomar@gmail.com","praveen.thakur@gmail.com","sarman.ali@gmail.com","zuber.khan@gmail.com","giriraj.singh@gmail.com","lokesh.sharma@gmail.com","pooja.pawar@gmail.com","nikita.sharma@gmail.com"),
                 name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))
```

i also have a same old data frame, to check if mail ID is present in old dataframe if present the check all records are same like (name,city,ID)

i have tried to use string_detect but it doesn't work.

output will be like

[image]

Comment: Can you post `old` in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(old)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(old, 20))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for the first part of the question:

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(first =str_extract(email, "[^\\@]+"),
         duplicate = as.numeric(duplicated(first)))
```

The first line extracts everything up to the `@` and the second line finds any duplicated observations of `first`.

Comment: Upvote but I would end the pipe with `select(-first)`, the auxiliary column is not in the expected output.